# Check if Cell value exists in Column and return a sum for a value in the same row but different column for each occurance

Tags: excel, indexing, sum, match

My end goal is to have a Column of salesmen and they're total amount earned in the next Column. I have a data sheet that has their name next to each sale they made. So I want to consolidate to just their name and the total amount of their sales in a new table. The data table will continue to grow.

Comment: Have you looked into pivot tables? You can then refresh the pivot table each time you need to view the total for the salesmen, and it's relatively easy to use.

Comment: I have not. They aren't my area of expertise, but I'm probably gonna have to give in eventually. So I may take that route.

Comment: @jcwynes If you can learn how to use it, you'll be able to run a lot of reports and you only need to use it a few times to get a good basic hang of how it works. The documentation on MSDN is relatively straightforward. Should you have any questions on pivot tables, you can ask on [superuser](http://www.superuser.com). Otherwise, I guess you can have a sheet full of formulae (they can be considered harder to learn than pivot tables ;) ), but if you want that, do say :)

Comment: I'll learn me some Pivot Tables then :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the basics, one minute should be ample. Select a range that includes names and sales (here A1:B7), Insert > Tables – PivotTable, PivotTable, OK, then drag the name field into `Row Labels` and the sales field into `Σ values`:

[image: SO18643130 example]

Then just play around, click a few button and see what happens - and explore other advice (on SO and elsewhere) because that is only the 'tip of the iceberg' in terms of how they may well be able to help you.